# Compress Decompressed Exe File

Tags: exe

So, I decompressed an exe file and modified it, and I want to recompress it back to exe form, not an SFX archive.

I can't find an internet solution for my problem, all of the posts I look at talk about recompressing to an SFX file, which I do not want to do, I want to convert it to a fully working exe.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `IExpress.exe`: https://www.maketecheasier.com/create-self-extracting-archives-without-installing-software/

Comment: The question is about repacking extracted `exe` file's content back to an `exe`.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying a binary file without breaking it requires a knowledge of hex or assembly. You can't just decompress and compress it back.

How ever there are tools that has ability to make some minor changes to an `exe` file. [This one is an example](http://www.restuner.com/howto-openfile.htm). Those tools can only alter `exe` file's resources like icons, some of the texts, images etc.

Hope this helped.